# Asynchronus Output in ssis Script Component Task

Tags: c#, ssis

In my Script Component Task i am getting the Error:
"In the buffer no line is included . A line must be possibly added with the help of the AddRow method."

I have alredy added the AddRow Method in my C# script,Here is my code:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{

   if (Row.Year.Equals(2014) || Row.Year_IsNull == true)
   {
         Otput2014Buffer.AddRow();

         //Transformation Part
         BudgetTotal2014 = ((Row.VpBudgetEVL2014 != null) ? Row.VpBudgetEVL2014 : 0) +  
                                       ((Row.VpBudgetEVG2014 != null) ? Row.VpBudgetEVG2014 : 0) + 
                                       ((Row.VpBudgetEVP2014 != null) ? Row.VpBudgetEVP2014 : 0) +
                                      ((Row.VpBudgetEVB2014 != null) ? Row.VpBudgetEVB2014 : 0);

        //Assiging values to Output Buffer
         Otput2014Buffer. BudgetTotal2014 = BudgetTotal2014;
    }
    else if (Row.Year.Equals(2015) || Row.Year_IsNull == true)
    {
         Otput2015Buffer.AddRow();

         //Transformation Part
         BudgetTotal2015 = ((Row.VpBudgetEVL2015 != null) ? Row.VpBudgetEVL2015 : 0) +  
                                       ((Row.VpBudgetEVG2015 != null) ? Row.VpBudgetEVG2015 : 0) + 
                                       ((Row.VpBudgetEVP2015 != null) ? Row.VpBudgetEVP2015 : 0) +
                                      ((Row.VpBudgetEVB2015 != null) ? Row.VpBudgetEVB2015 : 0);

        //Assiging values to Output Buffer
         Otput2015Buffer. BudgetTotal2015 = BudgetTotal2015;
     }
}
```

Any Suggestions what could be the Reason.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is it possible that Row.Year could be a value other than 2014 or 2015?

Comment: @Tab Alleman No there Could be NULL values but which is i am already setting to True and when i put a messagebox after Transformation it gets called but the messageBox after Assigning values to Output buffer is not getting called ..that means it is going inside if but have problem with writing to output buffer